# How to implement androidx work runtime in android.mk?

Tags: android, runtime, androidx, android-workmanager, android.mk

I am trying to add a library into my Android.mk file but I could not succeed yet.
There is the implementation of the library in build.gradle file as below;

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0"
```

In the Android.mk file I used something like that;

```
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
    androidx.work_work-runtime
```

However it gives an error when I build the project.

```
error: MyApp (APPS android-arm) missing androidx.work_work-runtime (JAVA_LIBRARIES android-arm) 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is intentional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
build/make/core/main.mk:846: error: exiting from previous errors.
```

So if anyone can help me here I would be so happy. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the definitions below into your makefile..

> ```
> LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
>   androidx.core_core
>
> LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
>   androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime \
>   androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-service \
>   androidx.room_room-runtime \
>   androidx.sqlite_sqlite \
>   androidx.sqlite_sqlite-framework \
>   guava \
>   workruntime
>
> LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
>   --extra-packages androidx.work
>
> LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := workruntime:libs/work-runtime-2.4.0.aar
> include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
> ```

Comment: Thanks @oguz-gencer. I was able to include androidx.work in Android.mk. During runtime I am facing this issue "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method noBackupDirectory(Z)Landroidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteOpenHelper$Configuration$Builder;" - in WorkManager.initialize(). Have you seen this ?